# ¿Cómo evitar que una columna en Bootstrap haga scroll con el contenido?

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy realizando un sitio con Bootstrap y tengo el siguiente problema, al hacer scroll en el sitio web, el sidebar lo acompaña y el contenido se pierde de la siguiente manera:

[image: Sitio sin scroll]
[image: Sitio con scroll]

El código es el siguiente:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap">
    <div class="col-auto d-none d-sm-block col-md-3 col-xl-2 px-sm-2 px-0 bg-dark">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center align-items-md-start px-3 pt-2 text-white min-vh-100">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col">
            {{- partial "header.html" . }}
            <div id="content">
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                <p>Hola</p>
                {{- block "main" . }}{{- end }}
            </div>
            {{- partial "footer.html" . }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

El objetivo seria que el sidebar mantenga el contenido en el foco de la pantalla ignorando la posición del contenido a la derecha.

Comment: Buen día, agrega `position-fixed` a las clases de tu `sidebar` por cierto tienes elementos con clases innecesarias o que se "cancelan" mutuamente, sería bueno que utilizaras el inspector y vieras en qué afecta cada clase

Comment: Gracias me ha servido tu respuesta, ahora tengo otra duda con respecto al propio sidebar, cuando la pantalla se encoge verticalmente no es posible hacer scroll en el sidebar, ¿hay forma de hacer dos scrolls independientes (tanto para sidebar como contenido)?

Comment: Otra duda = Nueva pregunta. No uses los comentarios para nuevas preguntas, gracias.